# accessing collection data from view in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I got fully stuck truing to understand how should I work with models and collections. Data is fetching from server into collection but then I do not know how to access this data in view to use it while rendering

here is my code:

```
ImmoObject = Backbone.Model.extend();

Realty = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ImmoObject,
    url: 'getall',

    initialize: function(){
        this.fetch();
    }
});

Application = Backbone.Router.extend({
    _realty: null,
    _view: null,
    routes: {
        "": "index",
        //"details": "details"
    },

    initialize: function(){
        this._realty = new Realty();
        if (this._view === null){
            this._view = new StartPage({collection: this._realty});
        }
    },
```

say, each ImmoObject have name. how I can go through all elements in collection (while rendering view) and output their names? Can I do something like this in StartPage.render()?

```
$.each(this.collection, function(k, v){
console.log(v.name);
})
```

Comment: If you don't want to extend model you can wright just this `ImmoObject = Backbone.Model;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `each` method of underscore.js :

```
StartPage = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $("#ul-immo-list"),

  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, "render");
    this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
  },
  ...
  render: function() {
    this.collection.each(function(immoObject) {
      console.log(immoObject.name);
      this.el.append("<li>" + immoObject.name + "</li>")
    }
  }
});
```

And in your router :

```
Application = Backbone.Router.extend({
  _realty: null,
  _view: null,
  routes: {
    "": "index",
  },

  initialize: function(){
    this._realty = new Realty();
    if (this._view === null){
      this._view = new StartPage({collection: this._realty});
    }
    this._realty.fetch(); 
  },
});
```

`this._realty.fetch();` will fire a `reset` event on the collection, which will re-render the the StartPage view.

Comment: but i can't work with this.collection in view cuz it say `this.collection is undefined`

Comment: make sure you pass "collection" in the constructor as Tricote's example above does. As well as having the _.bindAll() part as well (so the "this" is in the correct context).

Comment: yes i pass collection in view constructor and i have `_.bindAll(this, "render");` in StartPage.initialize But i still got `this.collection is undefined` while trying to do `this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);` in StartPage.initialize:

Comment: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2011/08/18/understanding-bind-and-bindall-in-backbone.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it in the render method.
Or in the addOne method of the application view.

The addOne method receives the model (if you keep your application code close to the demos) you should have something like this in AppView.

```
addOne: function(immo) {
  var name = immo.name; //Accesing the name for the model here
  var view = new ImmoView({model: immo});
  this.$("#todo-list").append(view.render().el);
},
```

Hope this helps.